# Run method before, at the end of it run other method

Tags: objective-c, class, methods, objective-c-blocks

I've a little problem and I don't know how can solve it.
I,ve a class Called Home, the entry point of my app in Objective-C, I would like run a simple method like this (4sec):

```
 [[SKTAudio sharedInstance] playBackgroundMusic:@"Intro.mp3"];
```

at the end of this method I would like run this(15sec):

```
[[SKTAudio sharedInstance]playBackgroundMusic:@"StoveGamee.mp3"];
```

This code run correctly but only one of this run in determinate moment.

Anybody have the solution... thanx a lot

Comment: Two ways to do it. The first one is to invoke the second method after a delay that equals the duration of the first clip. The other is to register an object as the delegate for the underlying `AVAudioPlayer` and get notified via `-audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:` (also maybe `+playSoundFileNamed:waitForCompletion:` (class method of `SKAction`) could fit better ?)

Comment: I tried a queue but I get this error: 2014-09-04 10:48:13.962 StoveGame[596:3603] 10:48:13.961 ERROR:     837: AudioQueue: request to trim 0 + 2136 = 2136 frames from buffer containing 1152 frames... I would like try second solution but I don't understand how register an object as delegate??

Comment: I hope that I've found the solution with this:-) [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"Intro.mp3" waitForCompletion:YES] completion:^{[[SKTAudio sharedInstance]playBackgroundMusic:@"Game.mp3"];
                    [BackGroundCommon sharedClassBackGround].playMusicBool = YES;  
                }